# Pentaho Report Designer - there is no field appears

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am using Pentaho Report Designer 7.  The database connection is OK.

Now, I wonder why on the Data Tab on the right side.  There is no fields from the query that I can click and drag it to the report?

It only show me the available Query names but NOT the fields that I can click and drag to the report.

Comment: what does the logs say?

Comment: I bet it's realted to a wrong sql statement ;D

Answer (score 1):

If your query is working fine(if you have checked at database level),in that case two possibility.

Case 1: In old PRD version you have to specify limit clause then only fields will appear which is quit a strange thing but is the solution.

```
Example : select * from tablename limit 100000;
```

Case 2 : if issue is not getting resolved by doing case 1 then, you have to right click on the queryname and click on select query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a right click on the query and select that query. It should show you output fields of that query.